# Calculated columns: Select which columns affect calculation

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have the following table:
SUM1 and SUM2 are calculated columns.

```
Org | A1 | B1 | C1 | SUM1 | A2 | B2 | C2 | SUM2 |
----|----|----|----|------|----|----|----|------|
 x  |  1 |  2 | 6  |   9  | 3  |  3 | 9  |  15  |
 y  |  2 |  3 | 5  |  10  | 4  |  5 | 3  |  12  |
 z  |  3 |  4 | 7  |  14  | 2  |  1 | 5  |  8   |
```

I would like to have a scatter plot, representing: SUM1 on X-axis and SUM 2 on Y-axis. I want one dot for each Org.

Also, I would like to filter which of A1, B1 or C1 is involved in SUM1 calculation. The same regarding A2, B2 or C2 and SUM2.
The effect I want to get is to visualize how each of these variables affects the total calculation plot when I take them out.

Is this possible at all? Is there another suggested approach?

Any comments will be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the issue by doing the following: 1. Unpivoting the original table 2. Calculating a measure for SUM1 and another for SUM2. Each of them, filtering the corresponding values from the attribute column. 3. Plotting the measures one on each axis and placing Org in "Legend" in order to have a dot for each Org. 4. With a slicer "Attribute SUM1" I can filter the values of the column "Attribute" of the unpivoted table (i.e the columns of the original table) that affect the measure SUM. Then I the same for SUM2

Answer (score 1):

Given that you "would like to filter which of A1, B1 or C1 is involved in SUM1 calculation", `SUM1` and `SUM2` cannot be calculated columns. For calculations dynamically responsive to filters/slicers, you need to write measures.